# How to change css for Jquery Datatable

Tags: css, datatables

I have a J query Data table, that outputs something like this: 
[image]

the code for the above datatable is:

```
$('#companies').DataTable({
    "aaData": data,
    "aoColumns": [......] 
});
```

> Please tell me how do I change the css (width, height, color etc) for pagination, search and no. of records?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can change the css of your required elements simply take the class/id name of element with its parent class/id. if not change then use !important tag to the style code. like:(example)

```
div#dataTable_filter {
float: right;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: 0px;   }
```